# Archive of a certain category in WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress, categories, posts

I would like to show archives from certain category only in my sidebar.

Something like..
Dropdown menu that has months/yeaars:
May 2011
April 2011
March 2011
Etc..

And beneath of it, would be list of posts of that seleceted month:
Title1
Title2
Title3

And if user would change the mont/year from the dropdown the posts beneath would change too.

I have some vague idea how this could be achieved and the way I am thinking would need lot of code/sql... any simple ways to do it? Has anyone done something like this before?

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of ways you could do this:

1. Load all month/year combinations from the dropdown on page load, and use jQuery/JavaScript to switch between the post titles for the selected year. (show/hide divs containing the archived posts)
2. Use Ajax to dynamically load the posts and make the dropdown field act as a get/post request. The get/post request can then be used inside query_posts to bring back the correct results.

Either way, to get the correct archives, I'd use query_posts to filter by year.

Comment: But how do I get corrent years/months to dropdown? The months that there's been posts etc.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure I understand your question.